# JSP and Spring Boot

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I trying to build a simple welcome page (in jsp) using Spring Boot.

Below is the project structure

[image]

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    public SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

}
```

**APIController**

```
@Controller
public class APIController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        System.out.println("testing");
        return "welcome";
    }
}
```

When I access `http://localhost:8080/`, I get below error

> This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing
>   this as a fallback.
>
> Wed May 23 15:31:51 MYT 2018 There was an unexpected error (type=Not
>   Found, status=404). No message available

By curl

```
{"timestamp":1527061233703,"status":404,"error":"Not Found","message":"No message available","path":"/"}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
    http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>spring-boot-web-jsp</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</name>
    <description>Spring Boot Web JSP Example</description>

    <version>1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- This is a web application -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Optional, test for static content, bootstrap CSS-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.7</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: What's the location of your welcome jsp file ?

Comment: @RichardK `WEB-INF  --> jsp  ---> welcome.jsp`

Comment: I guess you should return jsp/welcome

Comment: @RichardK still same..It only display testing in console

Comment: Can you also include all the dependencies ? (also the answer below may help)

Comment: @RichardK edited

Comment: have you added prefix and suffix for jsp file in application.properties file of spring boot app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the prefix and suffix for you jsp file in application.properties file like following:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: where should I create application.properties file ?

Comment: Spring boot created it by default in src/main/resources directory

Comment: can you show me the structure ? I tried but still failed

Comment: @Cyndi how you generating your project structure ?

Comment: It works now after I change to intellij..Before that I using netbeans, so the stucture a bit different

Comment: To start spring boot project i would recommend you to generate your project from [spring initializer](https://start.spring.io/) and import it in any IDE

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you have jasper and jstl in the list of dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Here is a working starter project - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-jsp

Comment: Added but still same

Answer (score 1):

In directory `\src\main\resources\static`, Create a simple `index.html` file

```
<html>
    <head>Hello, Bich Van</head>
    <body>
        <h3>Today is a rainny day</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then try again at http://localhost:8080

If you don't like static HTML files, you can use JSP, but need a little complicate. You need declaring JSP View resolver in Spring MVC configuration.

Reference document: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-welcome-page

Comment: I create HTML,but still same exception

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use **thymeleaf** in your spring boot project and add the following dependency
           `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
           </dependency>`

In directory **\src\main\resources\template**, Create a simple **index.html** file